# Content in Viewport (under topnav)

Tags: html, css

can someone tell me how I get the content always under the Navigation Topbar, when I navigate to that area?

[image]

When I click on "Portfolio", the content is always under the navbar. I want the content under it, how can I do that? Hope it's clear what I mean!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry not sure what you are asking. Do you mean that the content is getting cut off?

Comment: Post you current code so we can work with something also I have a vague idea of what you want to achieve but it is a guess so please clarify your question

Comment: If you provide your current code it will help tailor a solution to you specifically. This can usually be done using a `::pseudo` element to offset the top

Comment: Sorry totally forgot to post the code. @Pixell yes right!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #header {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 80vh;
    }
    
    #navbar {
        
        margin: 0 auto;
        
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 7vh;
        width: 98%;
        left: 1%;
        right: 1%;
        position: fixed;
        
        z-index: 700;
    }
    
    #container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
    }




     <div id ="navbar">
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="flex-item-left"><a href="https://kentzo.xyz">INDEX</a></div>
                <div class="flex-item-middle"><a href="https://kentzo.xyz/#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></div>                
                <div class="flex-item-right"><a href="https://kentzo.xyz/#contact">CONTACT</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="header">
            
    <div data-role="image-heap">
       <section data-role="image-container" class="left"><img src="https://kentzo.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/kentzo_glass.png"></section>
       <section data-role="image-container" class="right">
           <p>Hi I'm Jeffrey and Design rUns thru My VEins.</p> 
           <p>I lOve vibRAnt colorS And to eXpEriment.</p>
           <p>Born in MAnila,</p>
           <p>raIsed in FrankURt.</p>
           <p>HIre me!</p>
        </section>
    </div>

</div>
        
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="portfolio">
            <div class="mother reveal">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <!-- Post Wrap Start-->
                    <div class="flex_container" >
                        <div class="small flex_item"><h2><?php the_time('Y-m-d')?></h2></div>  
                        <div class="big flex_item"> 
                            
                        <h1>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h1>
                            
                        <div class="article_bild"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
                            <h2><?php the_category(', ') ?></h2>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                <!-- // Post Wrap End -->
    
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                
                <nav>
                <div><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                <div><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
                </nav>

                <?php else : ?>

                <h2>Not Found</h2>
                <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="contact"> 
        <p>you can write me on <u>hi(at)kentzo.xyz</u> or find me on <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeffrey-generalao-35ba57197/" target="_blank">linkedin</a> and on <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hauskatha/" target="_blank">instagram</a>.</p>   
    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the content goes "under" the navbar because it's fixed, so it will always be on top without taking any height space.
I see you give the navbar a height of `7vh`, so the easiest thing to do would be give the rest of the content a margin top of `7vh` too.
Since you have multiple sections, you just need to apply the margin to the first section after the navbar, in this case `header`.